# Android - Map fragment screen orientation crash

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using two fragment. One is a list fragment and the other one a map fragment.

The list shows list of places. When any item from the list is clicked the fragment is replaced and the place is shown on the map fragment with a marker.

The code that I am using when an item on the list is being pressed (in order to show the map fragment) is like this:

```
@Override
public void onPlace(Double lan, Double lat, String name) {  

    // Setting a LatLng variables according to the lan and lat that the
    // function received
    LatLng place = new LatLng(lan, lat);    

    // Getting the zoom by the user choice
    SharedPreferences userPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (userPref != null) {
        zooMao = Integer.parseInt(userPref.getString("zoomsize", "17"));
    }

    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
    options.camera(CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(place, zooMao));
    options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    Mapf mapFrag = Mapf.newInstance(place, name, options);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.phone_cont, mapFrag, "map");
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

As you can see I am using my own map fragment code - with the name -Mapf  - 
and this is the code for it:

```
public class Mapf extends SupportMapFragment {  
    private LatLng position;
    private Marker marker;
    private String name;

    // Creating an instance of the map fragment
    public static Mapf newInstance(LatLng pos, String place, GoogleMapOptions option){
        // Declaring an instance of the map object
        Mapf fragment = new Mapf();

        //Adding data to the fragment
        // such as position, name and map options
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //obtained by decompiling google-play-services.jar
        args.putParcelable("MapOptions", option); 

        fragment.name = place;
        fragment.position = pos;
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;   
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        initMap();
        return v;   
    }

    // This function adding marker and location name and position to the map 
    private void initMap(){

        // If there's a marker - removing it
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
        }

         // Declaring icon for the marker
        BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon);

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(position);
        markerOptions.title(name);
        markerOptions.icon(icon);

        marker = getMap().addMarker(markerOptions);

        // in case there's no name for the place - no need in a marker
        // using for the first loading of the map fragment
        if(name.equals("")){
        marker.remove();
        }   
    }
}
```

Now the thing is when I see the map with the current place - all is fine!

But when I am changing the screen orientation of the device, the app is crashing, saying that the marker is missing the place position's.

So what can I do in order to show the right place when the screen orientation is being changed?

Thanks for any kind of help.

and here's the logcat

```
01-15 13:22:06.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 13:22:06.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myplaces1/com.example.myplaces1.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no position in marker options
01-15 13:22:06.012: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You error indicates:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no position in marker options
```

The reason for that is that when you change orientation of the screen all the parameters you passed to your fragment are lost.

So what you need to do is:

```
 public static Fragment create(String vid) {
        VenueFragment fragment = new VenueFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_VENUEID, vid);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

as you already did with your `newInstance` method, but what you didn't do
is in `onCreate` do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CupsLog.i(TAG, "VenueFragment onCreate");
    mVenueId = getArguments().getString(ARG_VENUEID);   
}
```

basically your need to get the data you passed at instantiation and save it locally.

**UPDATE:** For your case of the LatLng do this, devide the LatLng object to two doubles:

```
 public static Fragment create(double lat, double lng) {
    VenueFragment fragment = new VenueFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putDouble(LAT, lat)
    args.putDouble(LNG, lng)
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

and in `onCreate`:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CupsLog.i(TAG, "VenueFragment onCreate");
    lat = getArguments().getDouble(LAT);    
    lng = getArguments().getDouble(LNG);
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your help - the thing i don't understand is how to pass the LatLng varibale to the onCreate? - can u be more specific please - shownig what should i do in the newInstance  and in the onCrate? - thanks